# Deploy Angular2 demo app within rails or as standalone app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, deployment, npm

I'm currently learning Angular2 and went through the quickstart and heroes tutorial. I'm always starting these apps with "npm start".

I've created a backend application in ruby on rails, and also have a frontend angular2 app. I do not know how I can integrate the angular2 app within the rails app. Theoretically, I can just put it into the public/ directory to make the JS accessible, but I probably need to convert it somehow so that the links are setup right.

Can anyone tell me how this is done normally?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in two ways as I can see

1 - Add your angular project folder to `app/assets/javascripts` or in the root in you app and set rails asset pipeline to use it. read more here (for angular1) https://thinkster.io/angular-rails

2 - Running as a separate project and use rails as only as an API. (this is my preferred method) due to following reasons.

- this will give a separation between your rails app and angular app. Basically you are forced to implement things in standard api way, like authentication etc. hence overtime you will have a more solid rails api and angular fronted
- once you have the separation, you can run these two in different app servers if you wish to. gives better load balancing etc..
- You can always replace both frontend and backend with different technologies later, like amber and node since they communicate only via an http api.

So this option will need more time and effort, but, if possible its defiantly worth it :)

Comment: You are right it would, of course, be better to have it as a separate project. However, as this is a micro app, I wanted to integrate - but as decoupled as possible. I thought it might be possible to just copy it into the project and create rails routes pointing to it, but I think there needs to be a bit more..

Comment: @chbla, Actually IMO its the syntax has changed from angular1 to 2. From the rails side, as long as you can compile it to assets it should run as angular1. I believe you should be able to use `grunt` or some task running to compile the js from ES6 to ES5. I would say, try an angular2 project in root of the rails app and set `grunt` to compile it and add to rails assets :)